# Hive cdh4 thrift setup throws NoSuchFieldError: METASTORE THRIFT RETRIES

Tags: hadoop, installation, hive, thrift, cloudera

I setup Hive cdh4 on RHEL 5 with remote metastore using mysql. I created a database, in mysql, with the same name as in hive-site.xml. I started up metastore server and hive server, but whenever I try to query hive, it throws me an error NoSuchFieldError: METASTORETHRIFTRETRIES.

I believe I'm unable to connect to metastore server or thrift server and this is causing this problem.
Please point me to the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you run mysql scripts for Hive from $HIVE_HOME/scripts/metastore/upgrade/mysql ?

Comment: Hi @Valery! Thank you for trying to help me. No, I did not run the scripts. Do I need to run all of them ?

Comment: no, I believe you need only hive-schema-<yours-hive-version>mysql.sql.

Comment: check this http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_4.html